# PHP Unable to convert variables to int

Tags: php

I'm struggling with converting variables from $_POST[] to int (long) in order to satisfy a function which takes long.

This function requires some input variables ($width and $height) which are both long. The script gets these variables from $_POST[] and they are of course string upon fetching. I have tried several methods for converting these variables into either float, int and long:

```
$variable = (float) $_POST["variable"];
```

and

```
$variable = $_POST["variable"] + 0;
```

and

```
settype($variable, "float");
```

But I still get the same error in error.log no matter what I do:

```
PHP Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in /bla bla bla/resize_image.php on line 30
```

It's gotten to the point where I'm tired of looking for solutions on Google since nothing seems to convert the damn thing anyway. So I'm asking you guys if there's something I'm overlooking or if this is even possible.

**get_image.php**

```
$url = "../../" . $_POST["url"];

$cropped = false;
$width = 0;
$height = 0;

if (isset($_POST["cropped"])) {
    $cropped = $_POST["cropped"];
}

if (isset($_POST["width"])) {
    $width = $_POST["width"];
}

if (isset($_POST["height"])) {
    $height = $_POST["height"];
}

//  Get image
$type = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($url);

if ($width > 0 && $height > 0) {

    include "Classes/resize_image.php";

    settype ( $width , "float" );
    settype ( $height , "float" );

    $data = resize_image($url, $cropped, $width, $height, $_POST["type"]);
}

$base64 = base64_encode($data);
echo $base64;
```

**resize_image.php** (Class)

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE, $type) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
$r = $width / $height;
if ($crop) {
    if ($width > $height) {
        $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    } else {
        $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    }
    $newwidth = $w;
    $newheight = $h;
} else {
    if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $newwidth = $h*$r;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        $newheight = $w/$r;
        $newwidth = $w;
    }
}

if ($type == "png") {
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
} else if ($type == "jpeg") {
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
}

$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

return $dst;
```

}

I'm in desperate need!!

Comment: Have you tried `floatval()`?

Comment: Looks like you called the function wrongly. `$data = resize_image($url, $cropped, $width, $height, $_POST["type"]);` should be `$data = resize_image($url, $width, $height, $cropped, $_POST["type"]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning

> PHP Warning: imagecreatetruecolor() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given...

means that the first parameter is a string. Let's look at the function call in `resize_image.php`:

```
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
```

The first argument is `$newwidth` which is assigned to either `$w`, or `$h*$r`. The result of multiplication is always a number (float or integer). However, `$w` is passed to the function without type casting:

```
if (isset($_POST["cropped"])) {
    $cropped = $_POST["cropped"];
}

// ...

$data = resize_image($url, $cropped, $width, $height, $_POST["type"]);
```

There is no type casting for the `$cropped` (the second argument) within the function, too.

So you need to cast `$w` to integer either in the function call, or within `resize_image`. It is better to sanitize parameters within the function body:

```
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE, $type) {
  $w = (int)$w;
  $h = (int)$h;
  // ...
```

Ah, and you probably didn't mean to pass `$cropped` as `$w`.

Comment: THANK. YOU. I can't believe I've missed that all the time.. It's fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the post is actually numeric.
Maybe try:

```
$int = (is_numeric($_POST['variable']) ? (int)$_POST['variable'] : 0);
```

Returns 0 if not numeric, you can modify as needed.